# multiple requests simultaneously, making strange results

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a confusing problem when I make several endpoints in spring boot to get data from mongodb

> mongodb version 3.6.8 with 3 cluster

I have tried to request each endpoint, and that response is normal, like this:

```
myhost:123/getId
```

> {"id":"123"}

```
myhost:123/getName
```

> {"name":"myname"}

When trying to do lots of requests and simultaneous. My query is normal, but sometimes the response becomes strange. like this:

```
myhost:123/getId
```

> {"name":"myname"}

or

```
myhost:123/getName
```

> {"id":"123"}

Thats will throw an exception, because key not found. I don't know where the wrong is, because it doesn't return an error. Only returns different results.

Comment: can you share what you have tried

Comment: i have tried to manual query 1 by 1 in mongo, its normal. And im try to request the endpoint 1 by 1 its normal too. but sometime its return same value in thats 2 endpoint when they request together, its strange because im not configure asyncronous thread in my program